# For loop with Multiple IF condition's in Shell scripting

Tags: linux, for

Firstly , In the `/tmp/test` file path I have the below directories

```
amb
bmb
cmb
```

By running the `find` command, I am getting the below list of files inside these three directories:

```
amb/eng/canon.amb
bmb/eng/case.bmb
cmb/eng/hint.cmb
```

I am trying to take each file from this `list1` using a `for` loop and based on the file type, `*.amb` or `*.bmb` or `*.cmb` that particulal IF should execute:

```
cd /tmp/test
find */ -type f -exec ls {} \; > /tmp/test/list1
for file in `cat /tmp/test/list1`
do
if [ -f *.amb ]
then
sed "s/amb/amx/g" /tmp/test/list1 > /tmp/test/list2
ls /tmp/test/list2 >> /tmp/test/finallist
fi

if [ -f *.bmb ]
then
sed "s/bmb/bmx/g" /tmp/test/list1 > /tmp/test/list2
ls /tmp/test/list2 >> /tmp/test/finallist
fi

if [ -f *.cmb ]
then
sed "s/cmb/cmx/g" /tmp/test/list1 > /tmp/test/list2
ls /tmp/test/list2 >> /tmp/test/finallist
fi

done
echo "*********************"
echo -e "\nFinal list of files after replacing from tmp area"
felist=`cat /tmp/test/finallist`

echo -e "\nfefiles_list=`echo $felist`"
```

So my final output should be:

```
amx/eng/canon.amx
bmx/eng/case.bmx
cmx/eng/hint.cmx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to apply a different action depending on the file suffix:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -d '' -r file
do
    # amb/eng/canon.amb
    extn=${file##*.}

    case "$extn" in
    (amb)   finallist+=("${file//amb/amx}") ;;
    (bmb)   finallist+=("${file//bmb/bmx}") ;;
    (cmb)   finallist+=("${file//cmb/bmx}") ;;
    esac
done <( cd /tmp/test && find */ -type f -print0 2>/dev/null )

printf '*********************\n\n'
printf 'Final list of files after replacing from tmp area\nfefiles_list=%s\n' "${finallist[*]}"
```

Incidentally,

- `find */ -type f -exec ls {} \; > /tmp/test/list1` could better be written as `find */ -type f -print > /tmp/test/list1`, and since you've tagged with [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) even that than be reduced further to `find */ -type f > /tmp/test/list1`. But this will break on strange (but legal) filenames.
- Backticks are deprecated and you should be using `$( … )` instead. But even that will break with filenames containing spaces and other special characters.

Comment: script getting failed at this step done <( cd /tmp/test && find */ -type f -print0 2>/dev/null ) as  No such file or directory

i  tried giving cat instead of cd to the file path , even though it is throwing same error

Comment: @afrin your own code starts with `cd /tmp/test` so I've used that as my starting point too

Comment: Could you please suggest, to get rid of this

Comment: @afrin no I can't. You have provided the information and requirements. I don't know your situation so if you say it shows that "X is true" then I work with the information that X is true.

Answer (score 2):

Use else if, aka elif in bash, e.g.:

```
if [ $something ]; then
    echo "something"
elif [ $something_else ]; then
    echo "something_else"
elif [ $nothing ]; then
    echo "nothing"
else
    echo "no match"
fi
```